# Update Diagnostic Logs Config for App Service Authentication Issue

Tags: azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

Setting App Service Diagnostic via the Portal is working fine resulting in the expected folders/files being created in the container. Where I am having an issue is with the automation of the process via `azure cli`.

When looking to automate with azure cli using `az rest` to Update the Diagnostic Logs for the App Service with `PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/config/logs?api-version=2016-08-01`, I can see that the configuration applied via this command is present via the resource explorer (and on the app service configuration app setting).

```
"applicationLogs": {
  ...
  "azureBlobStorage": {
    "level": "Information",
    "sasUrl": "https://<storagename>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>?st=YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ&se=YYYY-MM-SSTHH:MM:SSZ&sp=rwdl&spr=https&sv=2019-02-02&sr=c&sig=<sig>",
    "retentionInDays": 730
  }
},
"httpLogs": {
  ...
  "azureBlobStorage": {
    "sasUrl": "https://<storagename>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>?st=YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ&se=YYYY-MM-SSTHH:MM:SSZ&sp=rwdl&spr=https&sv=2019-02-02&sr=c&sig=<sig>",
    "retentionInDays": 730,
    "enabled": true
  }
},
```

and appears to match the configuration when applied directly via the portal except for the ordering of the values and the `sv` value, which is set to `sv=2019-02-02` for the default via the portal and `sv=2018-11-09` for the default set when using the `az storage container generate-sas`.

When checking the storage resource insight I can see Failures for AuthenticationError but when using the value added to the `sasUrl` via the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer application I am able to create folders and upload blobs.

Am I missing something, is there another setting required ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `az storage container generate-sas` we were using setting `https-only` which when removed allowed the logging to complete.